# playing video in OpenGL iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode5, video-player

With reference to the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620490/playing-video-on-ios-using-opengl-es) I am trying to render a video in OpenGL.But I am getting a black screen instead of the the video frames.Following is the method that I call for rendering the video.

```
 NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro_i-phone" ofType:@"mp4"]];
        mAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:NULL];

        NSArray * tracks = [mAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        mTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Tracks: %i", [tracks count]);

        NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
        NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
        NSDictionary * settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:value, key, nil];

        mOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc]
                   initWithTrack:mTrack outputSettings:settings];

        mReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:mAsset error:nil];
        [mReader addOutput:mOutput];
        [mReader startReading];

        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [mOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
        CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

        glGenTextures(1,&tID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tID);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 100, 100, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer));
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

Can anybody figure out what wrong am I doing?Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? What has been tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Basically I have added the following method and I just see a black screen.Where am I wrong because the above code works for one who has posted?

Comment: You should really analyze the source code and try to understand what it really does. Just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: I see generating a texture object (every frame? and never deleting them?) and providing it with data. I don't see any OpenGL draw calls that render geometry using that texture. Is that code somewhere else?